# How can I get the current node selected in a TreeView control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, treenode

When I use the `MouseClick` event of a treeview control always the first node in the tree is selected. What should I do to get the current node selected by the user? I am using C#.

This is the code I am currently using:

```
private void TVRecorder_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode selectedNode = TVRecorder.HitTest(e.Location).Node;
    if (selectedNode != null)
    {
        if (selectedNode.SelectedImageKey == "Test_Space")
        {
            frmRepository rep = new frmRepository();
            string ssql = string.Empty;
            rep.label1.Text = "Scenario-RepositoryDetails";
            rep.LoadAppSettings();
            SqlConnection con4 = new SqlConnection();

            con4.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + rep.ScnServer + ";" + "initial catalog=" + rep.ScnDbName + ";" + "User Id=" + rep.ScnUserName + ";" + "Password=" + rep.ScnPwd;
            try
            {
                con4.Open();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed");
            }
            ssql = "scn_select_testplan_sp";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(ssql, con4);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@testspace_key", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters["@testspace_key"].Value = testspace_key;
            SqlDataReader _datareader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            try
            {
                while (_datareader.Read())
                {
                    testplan_key = (int)_datareader["testplan_key"];
                    testplan_desc = (string)_datareader["testplan_desc"];
                    //selectedNode.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(Convert.ToString(testplan_key), testplan_desc, "P", "Test_Plan");
                    TVRecorder.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(Convert.ToString(testplan_key), testplan_desc, "P", "Test_Plan");
                    TVRecorder.Visible = true;
                    TVRecorder.HideSelection = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `WPF` or `WinForms`? Put some code as well.

Comment: it's a windows form application....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the **[`HitTest` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.hittest.aspx)** exposed by the `TreeView` control in conjunction with the location of the mouse pointer when the `MouseClick` event occurred ([**`e.Location`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.location.aspx)) to determine which node was clicked (and will therefore appear selected at the conclusion of the event). For example:

```
private void TreeView_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the node that was clicked
    TreeNode selectedNode = myTreeView.HitTest(e.Location).Node;

    if (selectedNode != null)
    {
        // ...
        // Do something with the selected node here...
    }
}
```

Notice that the above code checks to make sure that the `selectedNode` is not null before doing anything else with it. If the user clicked over something that is *not* a node, the `selectedNode` object that is retrieved by the `HitTest` method will be `null`.

It's probably not working for you now because you're trying to use the [`SelectedNode` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.selectednode.aspx) of the `TreeView` control. The node hasn't yet been selected when the code in your `MouseClick` event handler method is running—it will only be selected *after* that code has executed. Using the above method instead will allow you to get at the node that will eventually be selected more directly.

---

**EDIT concerning your update and comment below:**

This looks to me like a simple fix. The problem occurs in this line of your code:

```
TVRecorder.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(Convert.ToString(testplan_key), testplan_desc, "P", "Test_Plan");
```

The above code adds the new nodes as children of the first node appearing in your `TreeView`. Instead, it appears to me that you want to add them as children of the selected node. You've already determined what the selected node is (see above portion of answer), so you just need to modify your code to add the new nodes as children of the selected node, like so:

```
selectedNode.Nodes.Add(Convert.ToString(testplan_key), testplan_desc, "P", "Test_Plan");
```

Remember that every node (an instance of the [`TreeNode` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.aspx)) has a [`Nodes` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.nodes.aspx) that exposes a [`TreeNodeCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection.aspx). This collection holds all of that node's child nodes. MSDN probably explains this better than I can:

> The `Nodes` property can hold a
>   collection of other `TreeNode` objects.
>   Each of the tree node[s] in the
>   collection has a `Nodes` property that
>   can contain its own
>   `TreeNodeCollection`. This nesting of
>   tree nodes can make it difficult to
>   navigate a tree structure. The
>   `FullPath` property makes it easier to
>   determine your location in a tree.

Comment: Thanks Code Gray... but still i have a problen now i am able to  get the selected node but when i insert a child node the child node gets inserted in the first node and not in the node i selcted.This is the code am using....

Comment: @vikasse: Please edit your question to post the code you are using, rather than adding it as a comment. Comments don't get code highlighting or line breaks! No one wants to read that. ;-)

Comment: @vikasse: I've updated my answer. My eyes kind of glazed over with all of the try-catch exception handling in your code, but I think this does what you're trying to do.